# laravel-dropbox-driver throws exception when using laravel-backup package with cron

Tags: laravel, backup

I'm using spatie/laravel-backup package to backup my laravel project.everything works just fine on local.I uploaded my project on a host and set a cronjob to backup my data every midnight but it's not working.I found this exception from log files:

```
Starting backup...

In Client.php line 51:

  Argument 1 passed to Spatie\Dropbox\Client::__construct() must be of the ty
  pe string, null given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/benjamincrozat/larave
  l-dropbox-driver/src/ServiceProvider.php on line 17
```

But when I enter `php artisan backup:run` or any other commands from this package in the host command line ,it works fine.so  it just happens when using with cron.
note that I'm using DropBox for storing the backup files.
Why is this happening?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your `crontab` command so I can see if I can spot the error?

Comment: cron doesn't load .env parameters? because it turned out the missing argument is dropbox token that is loaded from .env file